# What is the jquery mobile event for when the user holds down a button?

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, touch-event

I have a popup that I want to make transparent when and for as long as the user presses and holds a button. And when they release, I'd like the popup to become opaque again.
What events should I be capturing to do this?

Currently, I'm using vmousedown and vmouseup events. They work, but once in awhile, when I press and then let go of the button, the vmouseup event seems to get fired. So when they let go, the popup remains transparent.

I've only experienced this on chrome on my iphone, never on the desktop.

First, am I using the event? Or is something better (like tap vs click) in the mobile world?
If I am using the right events, any idea why I have that odd behavior on mobile?

Answer (score -1):

try the $("...").on("taphold", function (event) {...});  event binding.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, or maybe I don't understand how it would be used for my situation. taphold event just seems to trigger after some elapse time. I don't see how this applies